# How to overwrite arduino library interruptHandler?

Tags: arduino, stm32

Good day!

I write code for an STM32f401xB/C board using the arduino IDE. I compile my code with stm32duino.

I am trying to write an EXTI interrupt handler but compiler flags me that I am trying to overwrite the handler function.

How should I go about with this problem?

Here is my code:

```
#define echo_pin PB9

void setup() 
{
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN;

  GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0x000C0000);
  GPIOB->PUPDR &= ~(0x000C0000);
  GPIOB->PUPDR |= 0x00080000; 

  pinMode(PC13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PC13, LOW);


  //enable clock and power on the syscfgen register
  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN;

  //there are 4 bits that have to be set to enable an interrupt
  //there are 4 EXTICR register each 16 bits wide
  //reset the bits in the register
  SYSCFG->EXTICR[2] &= ~(0x00F0); 
  //set interrupt on pin PB9
  SYSCFG->EXTICR[2] |= (0x0010); 

  //enables interupt on EXTI line
  EXTI->IMR |= (1 << 9);
  //set to trigger on both rising and falling edge, simulating the CHANGE
  //flag in attachInterrupt() function
  EXTI->RTSR |= (1 << 9);
  EXTI->FTSR |= (1 << 9);

  //enable the NVIC interrupt for EXTI9 to EXTI5 to lowest priority
  NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0x03);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
}


extern "C" { void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void){
  //check the pending bit of the PB9 pin
  if(EXTI->PR & (1 << 9)){
    //reset the interrupt bit
    EXTI->PR |= (1 << 9);
    digitalWrite(PC13, HIGH);
  }
}
}

void loop()
{
}
```

This is the error

```
home/admin1/.arduino15/packages/STMicroelectronics/tools/xpack-arm-none-eabi-gcc/10.3.1-2.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /tmp/arduino-sketch-E075A13F2405718203FB0E8501028A7D/libraries/SrcWrapper/stm32/interrupt.cpp.o: in function `EXTI9_5_IRQHandler':
interrupt.cpp:(.text.EXTI9_5_IRQHandler+0x0): multiple definition of `EXTI9_5_IRQHandler'; /tmp/arduino-sketch-E075A13F2405718203FB0E8501028A7D/sketch/Test Distance.ino.cpp.o:Test Distance.ino.cpp:(.text.EXTI9_5_IRQHandler+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the (relevant) code, and also the exact error message the compiler is giving you?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're running into is with your call to `Extern "C"`. Calling `Extern "C"` prevents name mangling which is what the C++ compiler uses to differentiate between functions with the same name. What you need to do is use `Extern "C"` to provide a linkage to the original C function and then provide a separate definition. If you want to read a little more about `Extern "C"` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-cplusplus) is a very brief intro. Depending on the version of the STM32F4 library you are using, you may also need to locate the "/stm32/{version}/libraries/SrcWrapper/src/stm32/interrupt.cpp" file and add `__weak` in front of the first definition of EXTI9_5_IRQHandler. This allows for a different definition of the function to be created but the original definition will remain as a fallback.

```
// Top of File
Extern "C" { void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void); }

// OTHER CODE

void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void){
  //check the pending bit of the PB9 pin
  if(EXTI->PR & (1 << 9)){
    //reset the interrupt bit
    EXTI->PR |= (1 << 9);
    digitalWrite(PC13, HIGH);
  }
}
```

This code cleans up the error but it is generally not common practice overwrite the default IRQHandlers. If you simply want to attach an interrupt service routine to the Arduino library for the STM32F4XX exposes a method called [`attachInterrupt`](https://github.com/bcmi-labs/arduino-core-stm32f4/blob/master/cores/arduino/interrupts.h). You can use it to assign a callback for an individual pin.

`attachInterrupt({Pin#}, {callback_function}, RISING)`. Rising can be replaced with falling or both as the mode for when the interrupt is triggered.

Comment: Yes but I want to program it in registers. And your sollution outputs the same error

Comment: @CristianCutitei Try navigating to where your arduino IDE saved the STM32F4 package and locate the EXTI9_5_IRQHandler function in the /stm32/{version}/libraries/SrcWrapper/src/stm32/interrupt.cpp and add __weak in front of it.  This should allow you to override the function. It looks like there are several different versions of the STM32 repo and some have this already included and some don't.

Comment: I can not seem to find the header file you are pointing to. Where can I find it?

Comment: Depends on your system. From the error log you provided above, it looks like `home/admin1/.arduino15/packages/STMicroelectronics/hardware/stm32/{version number}/libraries/srcwrapper/src/stm32/interrupt.cpp`.